# Windows Wamp: Mongo DB Extension not starting

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, wamp

I have install mongo db in my windows 10 PC using MSI download. My mongo db files are stored in

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB
```

My database is located in:

```
C:\data\db
```

I have tested that mongo db is running and the environment variable is set.

My php version informatin is:

```
PHP Version 5.4.12
Zend Extension Build    API220100525,TS,VC9
```

I have downloaded my mongo driver from :

https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

I am using  :

```
php_mongo-1.5.4.zip 
php_mongo-1.5.4-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll
```

I have renamed and loaded mongo extension in php.ini

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

I tried different version of the drivers are they were giving me compatibility issues but only php_mongo-1.5.4-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll worked without giving me an error or warning at wamp startup.

HOWEVER, when I look inside the checked extensions of php and mongo is not checked and even when I click to check it, wamp restart but its still not checked. Why isn't mongo db extension loading up in wamp?

I have checked php_error.log and there is nothing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is the process I used to get MONGO working***

First you have to download the Mongo Database manager itself and install it.
Download from 'https://www.mongodb.org/downloads'

So you can place the software yourself I would download the ZIP and NOT the .MSI this way you dont get your system messed with by
whatever the .msi devleoper thinks should be done to your system and you are in complete control.
Download the 32bit or 64 bit version to match your OS and WampServer(32/64) version you are running.

Now the Install is just a case of extracting the files from the zip and placing them somewhere on your system. I suggest :-

Copy the 'bin' folder from the extract to `c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z` ( x.y.z to match the version of mongo you downloaded).
Create a data folder under that folder, so `c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z\data`
Create a data folder for your first database under that folder, so `\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z\data\db`

Create a config file for mongo `c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z\mongod.cfg` and add as a minimum these parameter :-
NOTE: these are just params that will get it running, NOT A DEFINITIVE SET OF PARAMETERS!

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "c:/wamp/logs/mongod.log"
  logAppend: true
  timeStampFormat: iso8601-local

net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

storage:
  dbPath: "c:/wamp/bin/mongo/mongo2.6.6/data"
  directoryPerDB: true
```

Now if you want to have mongodb running as a service create a command file like so in the `C:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z folder :-

Filename = install_service.cmd

```
mongod.exe --config "c:\wamp\bin\mongo\mongo2.6.6\mongod.cfg" --install --serviceName wampmongodb --serviceDisplayName wampmongodb
sc config wampmongodb start= demand
```

For completeness also create an uninstall file :-

Filename = uninstall_service.cmd

```
mongod.exe --remove --serviceName wampmongodb
```

Now create 2 command files to start and stop your mongodb instance

Filename = start_mongo.cmd

```
net start wampmongodb
```

Filename = stop_mongo.cmd

```
net stop wampmongodb
```

Now start a command window using (Run as Administrator) and use these command files to install and start your MONGODB Server

```
CD \wamp\bin\mongo\mongox.y.z
#Install MONGO as a service
install_service
#Start the service
start_mongo
```

Now check the c:\wamp\logs folder and make sure there are no errors reported in the mongod.log file

While still in the command window, check that mongo is running by trying a few simple commands
Use the instructions here 'http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/' to prove that it is all working.

NOW ADD THE PHP Extension

Download from 'http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo'

Select the version you want and click the Windows icon with the word DLL beside it, in the 'Downloads' column.

This will take you to the download page for that version of MONGO.
You should now select the download link that matches the version of the MONGO extension you want,
and the matching (x86) for 32bit WAMPServer installs or (x64) for 64bit WAMPServer installs.
You must click the 'DLL' link otherwise you will get a unix/linux source code.

**Remember you must match the 32 or 64 bit to the version of WAMPServer you downloaded**
So if you are running Windows 64bit but installed WAMPServer 32bit you need the 32bit version of the MONGO extension.

Also remember that you need the Thread Safe version (TS) to run with WAMPServer.

Extract the zip file, and copy `php_mongo.dll` to your PHP folder eg '\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\ext'

Edit your php.ini file to add the new extension.
To use Mongo with your web server (Apache) use the wampmanager menus to edit php.ini i.e.

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

and add this line after all the other extension lines

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

To use mongo with scripts run from the command line (PHP CLI) edit '\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini' and add the extension line again in there

Start Wampmanager. Or Restart the Apache service.
This should refresh WAMPServers config and pick up the new PHP extension, if not do this when wampmanager is running:-

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service
```

Run localhost by :-

```
wampmanager -> localhost
```

and then click on the phpinfo() link on the homepage.

You should now see a section entitled 'mongo' with some configuration options listed. If you do the PHP MONGO extension is active.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and I already saw that in the other thread but I found was the problem was with my method. I was enabling the mongo db extension in the wrong php.ini file. There is a php.ini file in the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12 but that is not what wamp is loading its loading one from C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin. And when I added extension=php_mongo.dll in that file. extension was enabled.

Comment: I covered that in this line `wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini` That is how to ensure you edit the correct `php.ini` file